# svn settings overwritten by fabric

Tags: svn, fabric

It appears that fabric is overwriting my local svn user settings. The main bit of code that I can think of that would matter is:

```
env.svnuser = 'redmine'
env.svnpass = 'SomePassword'
```

So this sets `env.svnuser` and `env.svnpass`, and they are then used on the remote server (using `sudo`).

However when I next run svn locally, it appears that svn is using the username set by fabric - the stored subversion user in `~/.subversion/auth/svn.simple` is replaced with the value set in `env.svnuser`. Any idea how this could happen?

Answer (score 0):

fabric does have svn-specific code, and 'svn' string never occurs in fabric sources (at least as of 1.0.0).